# ¿Cómo extraer el número mayor y el número menor en una matriz? c++

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un problema en el que me plantea que de una matriz de números aleatorios pares, cuando imprima los números, el programa debe recorrer la matriz para imprimir cuál es el número mayor y cuál el menor, me gustaría que me orientaran a cómo podría hacerlo.

**Código:**

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int matriz [12][12];

    for (int fila =0; fila < 12; fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 12;columna++)
        {
            matriz[fila][columna]= 2 * ((rand() % 256) + 1);

            cout <<matriz [fila][columna] << " ";
        }
       cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<< "*************************************************" << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solo necesitas 2 variables una para el mínimo valor y otra para el máximo.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int matriz [12][12];
    int min=0;//valor minimo
    int max=0;//valor maximo

    for (int fila =0; fila < 12; fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 12;columna++)
        {
            int valor = matriz[fila][columna]= 2 * ((rand() % 256) + 1);

            cout <<matriz [fila][columna] << " ";

            if(valor<min){
                min=valor;
            }
            if(valor>max){
                max=valor;
            }
        }
       cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<< "*************************************************" << endl;
    //dabes imprimir el valor minimo y el maximo

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como comentario adicional, utilizando C++ en todo su esplendor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
// #include <cstdlib> // para std::system

int main()
{
  int matrix[12][12];

  std::generate(matrix, matrix + 12*12,
                [](){ return 2*(rand() % 256 + 1); });

  auto min_max = std::minmax_element(matrix, matrix + 12*12);

  std::cout << *min_max.first << ", " << *min_max.second << std::endl;

  // std::system("pause"); // Solo necesario para Dev-C++ Windows
}
```